# R-base could not be upgraded to 4.0: showing "r-base is already the newest version (3.4.4-1xenial0)"

Tags: r, ubuntu, upgrade

I have tried to upgrade R from 3.4.4 to 4.0 in Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (Xenial Xerus). I have followed and run the following scripts.

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9

$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran40/'

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt install r-base
```

Output:

```
"Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

r-base is already the newest version (3.4.4-1xenial0)".
```

The terminal always showed that "r-base is already the newest version" and refused to upgrade. I tried to upgrade R 3.6 as well and got a similar issue. Any thoughts? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: This might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237102/problem-installing-r-4-0-on-ubuntu-18-04 or this https://rtask.thinkr.fr/installation-of-r-4-0-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-and-tips-for-spatial-packages/.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. I first removed r-base and changed "deb https://cloud.r-project....." to "deb http://cloud.r-project...." (show error on https). R 4.0 was successfully installed at the end.